# Can I define a variable within setState in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am still new to React js.

I am trying to use `useState({})` to define an object of objects of `orders`.
For the `newOrderHandler`, I am passing the order to be added.

The idea is to add a new object if the order title does not exist and update the amount if the order title already exists in the `orders` state.

This is the code:

```
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState({});

  const newOrderHandler = (newOrder) => {

    setOrders(prevOrders => {
      console.log('prevOrderss', prevOrders)
      // console.log(`prevOrders[newOrder.title]`, prevOrders[newOrder.title])
      let newOrders = prevOrders;
      if (newOrders[newOrder.title] == null) {
        newOrders[newOrder.title] = newOrder
      } else {
        newOrders[newOrder.title].amount = +prevOrders[newOrder.title].amount + +newOrder.amount
      }
      return newOrders;
    });
  };
```

The problem here is that although when I log the `prevOrders` to the console, I get it as I wanted:

[image]

However, when I calculate the number of objects in the `Navigation` component, it just displays `0` always.

This is the code that calculates the number of objects in the `Navigation` component:

`Your Cart <span>{Object.keys(props.orders).length}</span>`

This is how I passed the props to the `Navigation` component:

`<Navigation orders={orders} />`

This always displays 0. I guess the problem is when defining this: `let newOrders` in the `setOrders` function, but I am not sure how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `let newOrders = prevOrders;` does not copy/clone/crete a new object. I suggest you should read reference types and working with immutable objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you React cannot detect that you have changed the object. You need to make a copy, you are passing in the same reference.

`newOrders == prevOrders` returns true.

What is standard is to make a copy so that you do not mutate the state and react can detect that the object has actually changed.

You can use the spread operator.

```
 let newOrders = { ...prevOrders, [newOrder.title] : { ...prevOrders[newOrder.title] }};

  if (newOrders[newOrder.title] == null) {
        newOrders[newOrder.title] = newOrder
  } else {
        newOrders[newOrder.title].amount = +prevOrders[newOrder.title].amount + +newOrder.amount
      }
      return newOrders;
```

Spreading the nested property too because you are mutating its `amount` property. For every level of nesting you will have to use spread for the property you want to change.

Comment: Glad. Please check edit, and read up on cloning nested objects.